# Place an icon on the buttom right of a Container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-design, dart-ui

I have a Widget to creat a circular container. I want to place an icon on the buttom right, so I tried to use Positioned to place it where I want but its not moving. Its fixed on the center on the container.

```
Widget buildImage() {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Material(
          child: InkWell(
            customBorder:  CircleBorder(),
            onTap: (){},
            child: Container(
              width: 150.0,
              height: 150.0,
              child:  Positioned(
                bottom: 4,
                right: 0,
                child: Icon (Icons.account_circle_rounded),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        decoration:  BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.orange,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Your answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try Align widget? You need to use alignment.bottomright property

Comment: Container widget has an alignment property, did you check it?

Comment: @YunusEmreÇelik Thanks for your fast response. That actually worked for me. I just had to add a padding widget.

Comment: @SiavashMirzaei-Fard Thank you for the response. I replaced the posioned widget with align widget and padding widget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positioned is used only in Stack widget. So if you want to position your icon inside Container, you can use Align widget, withPadding which will create desired behavior specified before in Positioned.
Somehow like this:

```
...    
Container(
                  width: 150.0,
                  height: 150.0,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.account_circle_rounded,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
...
```

Comment: Container has it's own alignment property, what's the point to use Alignment inside a Container?

Comment: same for padding

Comment: I totally agree and I would use these properties as well inside my app. But this way it might be more explicit for OP to learn about these widgets, and then even about these properties since he tried positioning with Positioned widget outside Stack.

Comment: @Nagual I tried using the Container properties (alignment and padding) and they gave me the same behaviour as wraping with align and padding widgests. Thank you for the useful comment

Comment: @DavidSedlář I appreciate your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Container has align property you can use that or instead of Positined you can use Alignment Widget for Aligning your widget

Answer (score 0):

For more control over postioning, just change the padding values.

```
                             Center(
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Material(
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      customBorder: CircleBorder(),
                                      onTap: () {},
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: 150.0,
                                        height: 150.0,
                                        child: Container(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                              right: 20, bottom: 10),
                                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                          child: Icon(
                                              Icons.account_circle_rounded),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    color: Colors.transparent,
                                  ),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.orange,
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
```